# Can you explain the output of the following structure code?

Tags: c, struct, printf

I have searched many articles on google for  following question but still not find any good answer.
From my first look ,I able to get that int x:3 here 3 is width if we assign x value greater than 3 some negative value get printed and if we assign value less than 3 ,the assigned value to x get printed correctly.
Can anyone explain how the output is coming of this code.

```
     #include<stdio.h>
      1  struct Point
      2  {
      3  int x:3, y:4;
      4  };
      5 
      6  int main()
      7 {
      8  struct Point p1 = {6,3};
      9 
      10 printf ("x = %d, y = %d", p1.x, p1.y);
      11
      12  return 0;
      13  }

The output comes as:

    x = -2, y = 3

when i included stdio.h header file warning vanished but the output of x get chnaged first without header file the value of x is coming -4 now with stdio.h header file the value of x becomes -2.Why this is happening??
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please format your code in a readable way. In it's current state, you're likely going to just receive downvotes

Comment: you don't have enough bits to store your values.

Comment: One of the warnings you show doesn't match the code you show. Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (without the line numbers, use comments to mark lines where errors or warnings are) and show the errors from that code.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude,I have compiled this code on c compiler it showing me this warning only,I have not made it myself.

Comment: No you have not compiled the code you show. The warnings contains a message about an assignment on line 11, but the source you show have not such assignment on line 11. Also the `printf` call is not on line 12 as reported. Please edit your question to include the *actual* code you used.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to store the value 6 into a signed integer of 3 bits, where there are 2 value bits and 1 bit reserved for the sign. Therefore the value 6, which cannot fit in the 2 value bits, is converted to a signed value in an implementation-defined manner. Apparently by using [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

"warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion" tells you just that. The compiler tries show constant `6` into the signed type bit field. I cannot fit - you get an overflow, and then there's an implicit type conversion to signed type.

Comment: "trying to  store the value 6 into a signed integer of 3 bits" --> it is ID if the field is signed.  `int x:3` could have functioned like   `unsigned x:3`, yet code did functioned like `signed int x:3` in OP's case.

Comment: `...there are 2 value bits and 1 bit reserved for the sign.` Well, that's not entirely correct in case of `Two's complement`. In `Two's complement` all bit represents a value and there is no sign bit.

Comment: @Lundin,when i included stdio.h header file warning vanished but the output of x get changed first without header file the value of x is coming -4 now with stdio.h header file the value of x becomes -2.Why this is happening??

Comment: @SahilAggarwal When you didn't include stdio.h, your old C90 compiler probably assumed the types to be `int` or something. Don't use C90 (or gnu90), it's old crap. `gcc -std=c11`.

Comment: @Lundin,I'm using C gcc compiler only,not using old turbo compiler.

Comment: @SahilAggarwal If you are using gcc which is older than version 5.0, it will default to `-std=gnu90`. From version 5.0 and beyond, it defaults to `-std=gnu11` which requires function prototypes. Better yet, you should use `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra`.